# Java-Tapestry, join between two entities

Tags: java, hql

I have three tables in my database: room, roomType and booking.

Room entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long roomId;

private Long doorCode;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "roomTypeId")
private RoomType roomType;
```

RoomType entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long roomTypeId;

private String name;

private String photo;
```

Booking entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long bookingId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "roomId")
private Room room;

private Date fechaR;
```

I want to make a join between Room and Booking to see which rooms are between some dates but when I try to make the join, I only can do it between Room and RoomType entities.

```
"SELECT u FROM Room h left join h.roomType"
```

How could join Room with Booking?